# UnimplementedError: Graph execution error during NLP model training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp

I am working on an NLP sentiment analysis model to classify the sentiment (neutral, positive, negative) of a tweet based on the content of the tweet on Google Colab. I have prepped the test_x and train_x data into sequences of ints using the Tokenizer module. I followed the Tokenizer tutorial on the official TensorFlow Youtube channel so there should be nothing wrong with that part.

However, when beginning to train the model, I run into UnimplementedError: Graph Execution.

I tried changing the layers of the model and decreasing the size of my data sets but the same error still popped up every time.

Could anyone clarify what this error means and is trying to say and also point out what is wrong with my code? Thanks!

```
import os
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
if len(device_name) > 0:
    print("Found GPU at: {}".format(device_name))
else:
    device_name = "/device:CPU:0"
    print("No GPU, using {}.".format(device_name))
```

```
# Load dataset into a dataframe
train_data_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/ML Datasets/tweet_sentiment_analysis/train.csv"
test_data_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/ML Datasets/tweet_sentiment_analysis/test.csv"

train_df = pd.read_csv(train_data_path, encoding='unicode_escape')
test_df = pd.read_csv(test_data_path, encoding='unicode_escape')


train_df.head()
```

```
# Function to convert df into a list of strings
def convert_to_list(df, x):
  selected_text_list = []
  labels = []

  for index, row in df.iterrows():
    selected_text_list.append(str(row[x]))
    labels.append(str(row['sentiment']))
  
  return np.array(selected_text_list), np.array(labels)


train_sentences, train_labels = convert_to_list(train_df, 'selected_text')
test_sentences, test_labels = convert_to_list(test_df, 'text')

print(train_sentences)
print(train_labels)
```

```
# Instantiate tokenizer and create word_index
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=1000, oov_token='<oov>')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train_sentences)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index

# Convert sentences into a sequence 
train_sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_sentences)
test_sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_sentences)

# Padding sequences 
pad_test_seq = pad_sequences(test_sequence, padding='post')
max_len = pad_test_seq[0].size
pad_train_seq = pad_sequences(train_sequence, padding='post', maxlen=max_len)
```

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(10000, 24, input_length=max_len),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(24, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

with tf.device(device_name):
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
num_epochs = 20

with tf.device(device_name):
  history = model.fit(pad_train_seq, train_labels, epochs=num_epochs, validation_data=(pad_test_seq, test_labels), verbose=2)
```

Here is a screenshot of the error:
[image]

Comment: Please post the error in text format (see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/)).